# Function to allow select a directory and run a command on its files, descending recursively?

Tags: files, whitespace, mapping

I sometimes work on legacy code, and they have mixture of tabs and spaces. I use `whitespace-cleanup` function in `whitespace.el` to clean them up. But I have many files, so i want to run the command on all of them (excluding the .git directory). What is the implementation of this recursive function call in elisp? My seasonal elisp skill does not let me do it right away.

Comment: One possibility: Mark the files in Dired, and act on them using a shell command or an Emacs-Lisp command. There are examples in the Dired files and library [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) of the latter.  See the definitions of `diredp-*-recursive` commands in [dired+.el](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Library [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) offers a bunch of commands that let you act on the marked files and the files marked in marked subdirectories, defined recursively. These commands have names like `diredp-*-recursive`.

It is also the case that you can insert any subdirs (and subsubdirs etc.) into the same Dired buffer, and then act on marked files there.

One of the Dired+ commands is `diredp-do-apply-function-recursive`, bound to **`M-+ @`**.  It lets you apply an Emacs-Lisp function to each of the marked files, defined recursively (see above).  Define a function that does what you want to do to *one* file, and then you can use `M-+ @` to apply it to all of the marked files (defined recursively).

> **diredp-do-apply-function-recursive** is an interactive compiled Lisp
>       function in `dired+.el`.
>
> (diredp-do-apply-function-recursive FUNCTION &optional ARG)
>
> Apply FUNCTION to the marked files.
>
> Like `diredp-do-apply-function` but act recursively on subdirs.
>
> The files acted on are those that are marked in the current Dired
>       buffer, or all files in the directory if none are marked.  Marked
>       subdirectories are handled recursively in the same way.
>
> With a plain prefix ARG (`C-u`), visit each file and invoke FUNCTION
>        with no arguments.
>
> Otherwise, apply FUNCTION to each file name.
>
> Any other prefix arg behaves according to the ARG argument of
>       `dired-get-marked-files`.  In particular, `C-u C-u` operates on all
>       files in the Dired buffer.

As you can see from that doc string, another command, **`diredp-do-apply-function`**, does the same thing, but only in the current Dired buffer.  It is bound **`@`**.  Use it if all of the files you want to act on are in the same Dired buffer (e.g., because you inserted their directories there).

Comment: This will surely do the job. I am just a bit hesitated to use it because I use ranger package at the moment. Reading through some threads on SO, I think it is possible for me to write a standalone function to do the job. Here are some answers by Chris Barret: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19508559/588867 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/14671532/588867 . I will however accept @Drew as a solution.